# rxvt-unicode - make fails with missing dependency

Tags: debian, make, dependencies, rxvt

I am trying to learn more about linux by exploring r/unixporn. I am running on Debian Jessie Xfce and I encountered following situation:
`apt-get install libperl-dev
git clone https://github.com/exg/rxvt-unicode.git
./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-everything && make`

Error:
`No rule to make target '../libptytty/src/ecb.h', needed by 'rxvt.o'`

I tried to install all packages returned from `apt-file search ecb.h` - it didn't help. I did also find this [github repository](https://github.com/yusiwen/libecb) but I don't know what to do with that. While I was having no idea what I was doing I just copy/pasted this lib into `/usr/local/lib`. It didn't help either. Now I am stuck :f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The three libraries that are within that repo give back a 404. You can get their contents here https://github.com/yusiwen. Just clone them in the very same directory you've just cloned urxvt and it should comply.

Comment: Thank you for the clone suggestion. It turns out that ```git clone --recursive git@github.com:yusiwen/rxvt-unicode.git``` solved a problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's no **library** in the github rep (only the **header** file).  Reading it, it appears to be self-contained.  If you put that in `/usr/local/include`, that particular problem would be solved.